# Task assignment email using Camunda-bpm-reactor

Tags: camunda, reactor

I am trying to re-implement [Task Assignment Email](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/usertask/task-assignment-email#task-assignment-email) using [camunda-bpm-reactor](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-reactor). I am able to send email when I am using Java classes, but when I try to re-implement it by event bus it does not work.

I added the required dependency as

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.quickstart</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-quickstart-task-assignment-email</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <name>Task Assignment Email</name>

      <properties>
        <camunda.version>7.10.0</camunda.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
      </properties>

      <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
          <artifactId>camunda-engine</artifactId>
          <version>${camunda.version}</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.1</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.8.2</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
          <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.171</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- redirect slf4j logging to jdk logging -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.12</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

      </dependencies>

      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>camunda-bpm-nexus</id>
          <name>camunda-bpm-nexus</name>
          <url>https://app.camunda.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </project>
```

to the pom.xml file of the project. I created three classes as follows:

TaskAssignmentApplication.java file:

```
package org.camunda.bpm.quickstart;

import org.camunda.bpm.application.ProcessApplication;
import org.camunda.bpm.application.impl.ServletProcessApplication;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngine;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineConfiguration;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration;
import org.camunda.bpm.extension.reactor.CamundaReactor;
import org.camunda.bpm.extension.reactor.bus.CamundaEventBus;

@ProcessApplication("TaskAssignmentEmail")
public class TaskAssignmentApplication extends ServletProcessApplication {

    private static ProcessEngineConfiguration CONFIGURATION = new StandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration() {
        { 
          // register the plugin
          this.getProcessEnginePlugins().add(CamundaReactor.plugin());
          this.databaseSchemaUpdate = DB_SCHEMA_UPDATE_DROP_CREATE;
          this.jobExecutorActivate = false;
          this.isDbMetricsReporterActivate = false;
        }
      };

      private static ProcessEngine processEngine;

      public static ProcessEngine processEngine() {
        if (processEngine == null) {
          processEngine = CONFIGURATION.buildProcessEngine();
        }
        return processEngine;
      }

      public static void init() {
        CamundaEventBus eventBus = CamundaReactor.eventBus();
        // create and register listeners
        new TaskCreateListener(eventBus);
        new TaskAssignmentListener();
      }
}
```

TaskCreateListener.java file:

```
package org.camunda.bpm.quickstart;

import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.DelegateTask;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.TaskListener;
import org.camunda.bpm.extension.reactor.bus.CamundaEventBus;
import org.camunda.bpm.extension.reactor.bus.CamundaSelector;

@CamundaSelector(type = "userTask", event = TaskListener.EVENTNAME_CREATE, process = "TaskAssignmentEmail")
public class TaskCreateListener implements TaskListener {

    public TaskCreateListener(CamundaEventBus eventBus) {
        eventBus.register(this);
      }

    @Override
    public void notify(DelegateTask delegateTask) {
        delegateTask.setPriority(97);
        delegateTask.addCandidateGroup("IT");
    }

}
```

and TaskAssignmentListener.java file:

```
package org.camunda.bpm.quickstart;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.commons.mail.Email;
import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.IdentityService;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.DelegateTask;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.TaskListener;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.identity.User;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.context.Context;
import org.camunda.bpm.extension.reactor.CamundaReactor;
import org.camunda.bpm.extension.reactor.bus.CamundaSelector;

@CamundaSelector(type = "userTask", event = TaskListener.EVENTNAME_ASSIGNMENT)
public class TaskAssignmentListener implements TaskListener {

  private static final String HOST = "smtp.gmail.com";
  private static final String USER = "camunda.bp@gmail.com";
  private static final String PWD = "";

  private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TaskAssignmentListener.class.getName());

  //private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

  public TaskAssignmentListener() {
    CamundaReactor.eventBus().register(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void notify(DelegateTask delegateTask) {

      //CamundaReactor.eventBus().register(new TaskCreateListener(null));

    String assignee = delegateTask.getAssignee();
    String taskId = delegateTask.getId();

    if (assignee != null) {

      // Get User Profile from User Management
      IdentityService identityService = Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration().getIdentityService();
      User user = identityService.createUserQuery().userId(assignee).singleResult();

      if (user != null) {

        // Get Email Address from User Profile
        String recipient = user.getEmail();

        if (recipient != null && !recipient.isEmpty()) {

          Email email = new SimpleEmail();
          email.setSmtpPort(587);
          email.setSSL(true);
          email.setTLS(true);
          email.setCharset("utf-8");
          email.setHostName(HOST);
          email.setAuthentication(USER, PWD);

          try {
            email.setFrom("noreply@camunda.org");
            email.setSubject("Task assigned: " + delegateTask.getName());
            email.setMsg("Please complete: http://localhost:8080/camunda/app/tasklist/default/#/task/" + taskId);

            email.addTo(recipient);

            email.send();
            LOGGER.info("Task Assignment Email successfully sent to user '" + assignee + "' with address '" + recipient + "'.");            

          } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Could not send email to assignee", e);
          }

        } else {
          LOGGER.warning("Not sending email to user " + assignee + "', user has no email address.");
        }

      } else {
        LOGGER.warning("Not sending email to user " + assignee + "', user is not enrolled with identity service.");
      }

    }

  }

}
```

But it does not work. any ideas why?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I don't receive any errors. Just don't receive any email in my mailbox, does not set the priority and does not set the user group.

Comment: Who calls init() to register the Listeners?

Comment: How can I call it? I created a new JavaDelegate class and called it in the execute method but now I am getting the following error. "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No eventBus found. Make sure the Reactor plugin is configured correctly."

Comment: How are you running your app?   Seems to me, since you are extending the ServletProcessApplication, that you are running on Tomcat? In that case the engine is managed by tomcat (platform.xml). Your static configuration, engine and init code is useless, since it is never called.   You will have to put the reactor jars in tomcat/lib and add the plugin to the platform.xml. This is no simple matter ... if you are new to the subject, maybe you should warm up with something simplier, like using the spring boot starter?